# Shadow of scroll bar appearing on top of overlay animation in Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have an html page with an opening animation that covers the whole page using an overlay. The animation is a simple fade out of an image using jquery. The animation is triggered by $(document).ready. In the background, the rest of the html is being dynamically generated by javascript, and one of the div has a scroll bar. My problem is: in Chrome and Safari, the "shadow" of the scroll bar flashes/appears on top of the animation during the opening animation, even though it's behind the animation layer. What can I do to make this stop?

Answer (score 0):

Played around and finally figured a way out:
make $("div").css({"overflow-y":"hidden","overflow-x":"hidden"}); before animation starts,
then $("div").css({"overflow-y":"","overflow-x":""}); after animation finishes.